# Can the focus point for a Nikon D7500 be positioned while tethering to a PC using Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, tethering, focus-point-selection, nikon-d7500

While tethering my Nikon D7500 to my laptop using Windows 10 Adobe LightRoom I noticed I can't see the focus point like I can while in my camera's LiveView.

I often move the focus point on my Nikon D7500 while in LiveView for the following reasons:

- To zoom in using the plus button on the camera back side to see if
  something like a person's eye is in focus.
- To allow for spot metering to use the location of the focus point as
  the point for metering.

Is there a way to see where the focus point is while using Adobe LightRoom and if so can I move it for the 2 reasons I described above?

Comment: To show focal points I know only one plugin: https://lightroomfocuspointsplugin.com/ . But I have my doubts will work in tethering mode, not talking about move them.

Comment: If you zoom in to the eye, why not focus manually while there? In constant light, why not lock exposure by using P or M mode? Live view makes getting the pictures you want easier.

Answer (score 1):

You need software that can use the live view feed for tethered shooting in order to see/control the focus points/focus. The latest versions of Lightroom Classic  (10.3+) only supports a very limited number [of Nikon cameras](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/kb/tethered-camera-support.html#live-view-support-nikon) for this.

You can use open source software with that capability such as [digiCam control](http://digicamcontrol.com/) instead, or purchase a plugin for Lightroom Classic such as [Smart Shooter 4](https://tethertools.com/product/smart-shooter-4/).

Comment: I did not found in Smart Shooter any mention of focal point, the only helpful view was zoom...